# Detect variable change on runtime

Tags: javascript

I'm working with the web audio API. In `note.js` i try to fill an array with some couple of notes for `index.js` to play. But it does not work as intended. However, when i set the array directly in `index.js` it works.
I have no clue why it is like that. Basically i want `index.js` to play whatever notes gets pushed into the array in `note.js`. Below i have pasted the two versions of `index.js` to demonstrate what i want to do.

Hope someone can help me with this one.

index.js (does work)

```
import NoteModule from './note.js';
const notelist = new NoteModule();

notelist.notes = ['C4','D4','E4','F4','G4','A4','B4','C5'];

let seq = new Tone.Sequence(function(time, note){
    event.humanize = true;
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,'8n');

}, notelist.notes, '8n');
```

index.js (does not work)

```
import NoteModule from './note.js';
const notelist = new NoteModule();

let seq = new Tone.Sequence(function(time, note){
    event.humanize = true;
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note,'8n'); 

}, notelist.notes, '8n');
```

note.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class NoteModule {
constructor(possibleNotes,notes,note) {
    this.possibleNotes = ['','C4','D4','E4','F4','G4','A4','B4'];
    this.notes = notes;
    this.note = 0;
}

init() {
    console.log('NoteModule');
    this.addListeners();
}

addListeners() {
    $('div.step').on('click', this.step.bind(this));
}

step(e) {

    let notes = [];

    $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.note').text(this.possibleNotes[this.note]);
    this.note = (this.note+1)%(this.possibleNotes.length);

    $('.pads div.note').each(function() {
        let note = $(this).text();

        if (note && note.length > 0) {
            notes.push(note);
        }
    });

this.notes = notes;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
                    <div class="pads">                    
                        <div class="pad"><div class="note" data-play=""></div></div>
                        <div class="pad"><div class="note" data-play=""></div></div>
                        <div class="pad"><div class="note" data-play=""></div></div>
                        <div class="pad"><div class="note" data-play=""></div></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pads">
                        <div class="pad">
                            <div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-up-open-mini"></i></div>
                                <div class="note"></div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-down-open-mini"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pad">
                            <div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-up-open-mini"></i></div>
                                <div class="note"></div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-down-open-mini"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pad">
                            <div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-up-open-mini"></i></div>
                                <div class="note"></div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-down-open-mini"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pad">
                            <div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-up-open-mini"></i></div>
                                <div class="note"></div>
                                <div class="step"><i class="icon-down-open-mini"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: In the second version your `notelist.notes` isn't filled in result.
You are only initializing `possibleNotes`, not `notes` property

Comment: @lunochkin Thank you, and how would i do that? I men, i do "notes.push(note);" in the end of the file..

Comment: As I've got it's supposed to fill `notes` with clicks on `div.step`, but I don't see call of `init()` method with addListeners. So, may be it's related to problem.

Comment: Thats exactly what i want to do, to run init(); does not make any difference tho. When i log the array it displays what it should.

Comment: Also you may be need to initialize `seq` again after `notelist.notes` changes, but I'm not sure. Depends on how `Tone.Sequence` works

Comment: Right now "seq" does not play the notes att all (in the none working index.js example.). Any ideas?

Comment: I'll look into this if you can provide the html (paste it somewhere online)

Comment: @user2952238 gonna need more than that since I want to reproduce it on my machine (or preferably online) to see what is exactly going wrong

Comment: @d9ngle hm, its written in es6 and needs compiling so thats not the easiest. I could send you The repo or zip tho if you want to run in on your machine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to rework a bit how your files are structured and how your module is working. It does not work, because you are creating the `Tone.Sequence` before anything has the chance to be set in your `NoteModule` class, and you are not really updating your notes array anyway, you also didn't bind your `step` method in your constructor, meaning it won't have access to the `this` context, leaving all your modifications not saved.

Refactor your module to do something like the following, passing a function callback that will be executed once you click on a play button (that you will have to create). If you want to play as soon as a new note is played, just call the callback like I did in the `step` method.

```
import $ from 'jquery'

export default class NoteModule {

  constructor (callback, notes) {
    this.possibleNotes = ['','C4','D4','E4','F4','G4','A4','B4']
    this.notes = notes
    this.callback = callback
    this.note = 0
    // you need this otherwise the step method won't have access to the context
    this.step = this.step.bind(this)
  }

  init () {
    console.log('NoteModule')
    // make sure this is called, otherwise your events won't work
    $('div.step').on('click', this.step.bind(this))
    $('.play').on('click', () => this.callback(this.notes))
  }

  step (e) {

    const notes = []

    $(e.currentTarget).parent()
      .find('.note')
      .text(this.possibleNotes[this.note])

    this.note = (this.note + 1) % (this.possibleNotes.length)

    $('.pads div.note').each(el => {
      const note = $(el).text()

      if (note && note.length > 0) {
        notes.push(note)
      }
    })

    this.notes = notes
    // or callback here, as you want

  }
}
```

And in your `index.js` simply import, initialize your class and pass the function callback that will receive the notes:

```
import NoteModule from './note.js'

const callback = notes => {
  const seq = new Tone.Sequence((time, note) => {
    event.humanize = true
    synth.triggerAttackRelease(note, '8n')
  }, notes, '8n')
}

new NoteModule(callback)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I have now added your code. So now my files looks exactly like the code you pasted. Id does not work tho. Have i missed something? This callback function, should i add that myself? Cant see it in your code.

Comment: The callback function is the first parameter being passed to the class. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: The notes array does not get populated. its something with the step() function in the NoteModule class.

Comment: Can you do your `this.notes = ['C4','D4','E4']` inside the `step` function and call the callback directly? It might be an issue with your jquery code too

Comment: Yes, that works. now i get "Uncaught TypeError: _this.callback is not a function" when clicking on play. Obviously notemodule does not have that function. What is that function supposed to do?

Comment: Cool, did you changed your `index.js` accordingly? is your constructor set correctly too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144784/discussion-between-apercu-and-user2952238).